# Swift Generic Type Problem: "Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'"

Tags: swift, loops, generics

here is my problem:

```
struct NewStack<S> {
    var stacks = [S]()
    mutating func addS(_ s: S) {
        stacks.append(s)
    }
    mutating func removeLastS() {
        stacks.removeLast()
    }
}
var newStacks = NewStack<String>()
newStacks.addS("Eins")
newStacks.addS("Zwei")
newStacks.addS("Drei")


for stack in newStacks.stacks {
    var stackCount = 1
    repeat {
    stackCount + 1
    } while stackCount <= newStacks.stacks.count {
            print("Stack \(stackCount) = \(stack)")
        }
    
    
}
```

At the line with the while-Statement it throughs me the warning: Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int'
Ìt would be very helpful if someone could tell me what I have to do, thank`s

Comment: `stackCount  = stackCount + 1` change this line

Comment: The body of the loop is between `repeat {` and `} while`, so if that print statement is supposed to be part of the loop then move it inside the body of the loop

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax issues with your code.
First, `stackCount + 1` doesn't increment `stackCount`, to do that, you need `stackCount += 1`. Secondly, you cannot have code executed in the `while` condition, you need to move the `print` inside `repeat`.

```
for stack in newStacks.stacks {
    var stackCount = 1
    repeat {
        stackCount += 1
        print("Stack \(stackCount) = \(stack)")
    } while stackCount <= newStacks.stacks.count
}
```

Comment: @ChristophDrescher Glad I could help. If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it. If you're unsure how to do that, you can read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to have an inner loop, you can use a simple for loop like this

```
for stack in newStacks.stacks {
    print("Stack \(stack)")
}
```

Or if you want the index to be printed as well (I added + 1 so the printed index start at 1)

```
for (index, stack) in newStacks.stacks.enumerated() {
    print("Stack \(index + 1) = \(stack)")
}
```